# This appears to create an object from an interface; how does it work?

Tags: java, interface, object

```
interface Int {
   public void show();
}
```

```
Int t1 = new Int() {
   public void show() {
      System.out.println("message");
}

to.show();
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're defining an anonymous class that implements the interface `Int`, and immediately creating an object of type `thatAnonymousClassYouJustMade`.

Comment: This is really useful for event handlers (such as those that use the ActionListener interface).

Comment: I'm not quite sure, which of course is a sin to be punished for. For me, it's more a matter of perspective. From perspective of author of the code he declares a field, and this field has a type, given before it's name. That's clean imho explanation.  It's more vivid when de declare default method in interface actually doing smth and we leave the body of anonymous class completely empty, so the only functionality of a new object comes from default method of in interface.

I know that in reality, anonymous class is created, but just wondering if approach given above cannot be at least concider

Answer (score 8):

This notation is shorthand for

```
Int t1 = new MyIntClass();

// Plus this class declaration added to class Test
private static class MyIntClass implements Int
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("message");
    }
}
```

So in the end you're creating an instance of a concrete class, whose behavior you defined inline.

You can do this with abstract classes too, by providing implementations for all the abstract methods inline.

Answer (score 4):

What this special syntax for anonymous inner classes does under the hood is create a class called `Test$1`. You can find that class file in your class folder next to the Test class, and if you printed `t1.getClass().getName()` you could also see that.

Answer (score 0):

i think your object has nothing to do with the interface. If you comment out the whole interface, still you will get the same output. Its just anonymous class created. I think, unless you use the class "implements" you cant implement the interface. But i dunno how naming collision doesn't  happen in your case.

Comment: The anonymous class definitely implements the interface, and `t1 instanceof Int` will be true.