# Object of an Interface

Tags: java, oop, interface

I have query about this code:

```
ClassA {
  main() {
    List<Object> L1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    System.out.println(L1.getClass().getName());
  }
}
```

The output:

```
java.util.ArrayList
```

I have seen another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947708/this-appears-to-create-an-object-from-an-interface-how-does-it-work) , where `class.getName()` gives the name of the encloing class i.e `Test$1` as the annoymous class.

Why did i get name of `arrayList` as class name but not `A$1`?

Comment: Because you don't have an anonymous class.

Comment: try making object using anonymous inner class and print

Answer (score 0):

simply because the class `ArrayList` is **not defined** in your class `ClassA` . It is defined in `java.util` package 
PS: you can't create object of an interface , but you can implement the interface and create instances of it

eg :

```
instance I{}
class C implements I{}
```

this is not legal : `I i=new I();`
this is OK : `I i=new C();`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing **Generics** with inner and anonymous classes.   In some sense you are right, but the biggest differentiation of a Generic class is that it is erased at compile time.

This means you can't query it at run time.

So `ArrayList<String>` is just an `ArrayList` where the compiler makes sure you never stick a non-String into it or have to manually cast the retrieved contents to `String`.

The other kinds of classes are real classes, despite the odd naming conventions that occasionally crop up.

Answer (score 0):

`L1` holds the reference of `ArrayList`, so when you will call `L1.getClass()` then it will return the class type `class java.util.ArrayList` and `L1.getClass().getName()` will return `java.util.ArrayList`.

`getName()` : the name of the class or interface represented by this object

in your case this object is `L1` which holds the reference of `ArrayList`.