# Creating an object of an interface in C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented-analysis

I know this question is a bit odd, but please bear with me.

I am designing an OOD for a parking lot.  I want to allow only those vehicles to park, that have an `autopark` feature in them.  In Java, I would have created an interface and only the objects of that interface (i.e., the cars with `autopark` features) would have been allowed to park.  In C++, interfaces are created using abstract classes with pure virtual methods.  So, I cannot create objects of this 'C++ interface'.  So, how do I achieve this in C++?

Note:  I know of other techniques like using some flag to denote the presence or absence of `autopark` feature, etc; but I am not interested in those workarounds.

Comment: You can't create objects of an interface type in Java, either. There's no difference there.

Comment: @chris, using an anonymous class?  Something like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947708/this-appears-to-create-an-object-from-an-interface-how-does-it-work)?

Comment: That's creating an object of a concrete anonymous class that implements the interface.

Comment: Java question tag removed. You may be discussing Java in your question, but it is all about C++.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, sorry.  And thank you for the tag-removal.

Comment: Interfaces cannot be instantiated just as abstract classes in C++ cannot be... You need to inherit from the abstract class as you would `implement` the interface in Java. Same stuff applies.

Comment: `dynamic_cast<autopark *>(address_of_some_object)` gives `NULL` (or, in C++11 `nullptr`) if `some_object` is NOT of a type derived (accessibly) from `autopark`.

Comment: @c650, and then pass the objects of the derived classes of the abstract base class, as they would have the `autopark` feature, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a way to create anonymous concrete classes.

In C++, you can create anonymous structures by treating the structure/class as the 'type' for a variable declaration. Below, we have the implementing class (note that it's anonymous but still extends `Foo`, our pure-virtual/'abstract' base class) and instead of ending with the semicolon, we give it a variable name to immediately allocate an instance of that anonymous class on the stack.

Consequently, this is why classes, structs and enumerations in both C and C++ must end with a semicolon (whereas things like `namespace` do not).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

void callBar(Foo *foo) {
    foo->bar();
}

int main() {
    class : public Foo {
        virtual void bar() {
            cout << "Hello from foo1" << endl;
        }
    } foo1; // <-- Note that we immediately create foo1 here...

    class : public Foo {
        virtual void bar() {
            cout << "Bonjour from foo2" << endl;
        }
    } foo2; // <-- ... and foo2 here.

    callBar(&foo1);
    callBar(&foo2);

    return 0;
};
```